# Why do arguments to a function get filled up in registers in reverse order in C?

Tags: c, function, gcc, cpu-registers

This is a simple function:

```
void dab(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    printf("Hallo: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

It does almost nothing except print the arguments just for the sake of showing that they are passed in correctly.

Now, I'll call the funtion:

```
int main() {
    dab(6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

Simple call, nothing weird. See the assembly compiled by gcc 9.4.0 that calls the function:

```
movl    $9, %ecx
movl    $8, %edx
movl    $7, %esi
movl    $6, %edi //Goes in reverse, right to left
call    dab
```

Logically, one would think it would be filled from left to right(the way we type). In this order: 6, 7, 8, 9. But it is instead from right to left. In this order: 9, 8, 7, 6. Wouldn't it make more sense to have it filled from left to right like this:

```
movl    $6, %edi
movl    $7, %esi
movl    $8, %edx
movl    $9, %ecx //Goes from left to right, the intuitive way
```

I know it makes no difference but while coding but isn't intuition and simplicity for the sake of readability important? Just in case, I tested it and both ways of filling it in give the same result which is

> Hallo: 6, 7, 8, 9

Wouldn't it be easier to read and make more sense for the compiler manufacturer if the arguments were filled from left to right and not right from left?

Btw, Hallo is not a typo. It's intended

Comment: Your 2 versions use the registers in the very same way. How does it matter in which order assembler instructions are placed? Any optimizing compiler will apply much more instruction reordering anyway. Also that is nothing related to C standard. The standard does not define anything about register or memory usage

Comment: @Gerhardh It matters for readability. Not like non ordered filling would be unreadable but it is good to follow perfect intuition in a sector where a minor typo can get you stuck for days. And if it's not related to C-standard, I'll just add my compiler info and fix the problem and make it compiler specific.

Comment: What readability? Such autogenerated code is not meant to be read.

Comment: Right to left *is* the intuitive order.

Comment: @user3386109 at least for those of us who are aware of passing parameters via stack.

Comment: @Gerhardh Don't you have to view the disassembly sometimes? It's important. And sometimes a lot of assembly needs to be mixed with C and auto generated code needs to be read.

Comment: I never had to look at the assembler code except when running a debugger for the last 20 years. And coming from a world where standard for parameter passing was via stack rather than registers, everything had to be pushed from right to left anyway.

Comment: How would you mix parameters in registers with parameters on stack (for functions with variadic parameters)? Would you push from right to left on the stack and fill the other parameters from left to right? Yikes!

Comment: @Gerhardh Okay now I get it. It makes sense with the stack. You could've said this before. Turns out there was a reason and that contradicts your "How does it matter". Turns out tit does matter when passed from the stack.

Comment: @Gerhardh parameters passed via registers are pushed to *named* locations matching call indexes (AFAIK most architectures don't really support pushing / popping multiple registers at once, `pusha``/`popa` notwithstanding), so there is no observable difference between filling registers LTR or RTL.

Comment: @Masklinn I am not sure where "pushing" registers fits in here. If I need to pass parameters via R8-R12, They need to be filled in given order of values. But of course order of instructions does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

This is for the convenience of the callee: if the parameters were pushed in "call" order, then the "first" parameters available to the callee would be the "last" of the call.

```
param0
param1
param2
param3
return address
<- top of stack is here
```

do you'd have to reverse all your offsets when trying to compute your parameters.

By pushing in reverse order, the callee gets the arguments in a more sensible order: param 0 is at offset 0 (+ some constant offset):

```
param3
param2
param1
param0
return address
<- TOS
```

This is even more important when the function being called takes a variable number of arguments: if the callee doesn't know the number of arguments it can't even access the "fixed arguments" if pushed in call order. Whereas in reverse order it can trivially access the fixed arguments (such as the number of arguments passed in), or it can easily use a placeholder scheme e.g. `0` or `null` to indicate the end of the arglist.

Comment: The OP's assembly is not using stack at all though. Looks like some non-standard calling convention similar to fastcall.

Comment: Modern calling conventions (and compilers when performing internal calls) will bypass the stack for some number of arguments, but the cdecl logic remains in the arguments-pushing, if only because the "spill" will still be passed through the stack. So it makes more sense to keep working that way. For instance AMD64 uses registers for the first 6 integer (/pointer) arguments and the first 8 floating-point arguments, the rest goes on the stack right-to-left.

Comment: Ah, I can see it with `gcc -O3`. It adds them in the order 8, 7, 9, 6, though.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it makes no difference but while coding but isn't intuition and simplicity for the sake of readability important? Wouldn't it be easier to read and make more sense for the compiler manufacturer if the arguments were filled from left to right and not right from left?

The readability of the generated assembly is in general not important. Only the readability of the source code. When turning on optimizations the assembly code usually turns into a total mess when it comes to readability.

Also, what makes most sense here is highly platform dependent.

Answer (score 2):

This is, at most, an echo of history and has no significance in modern use of the x86 architecture.

In early computers, if you wanted arguments A, B, and C on the stack in that order, so that a called function would see A, B, and C in that order as it “popped” arguments from the stack, then you would push them in the reverse order, C, B, and A, because stacks are last-in-first-out.

Current practice in modern systems is largely to reserve a whole stack frame at once and then write to locations within the frame using offsets from the frame pointer. We can write the arguments, A, B, and C in any order we desire and get them to the right places in the stack by using offsets to those locations. In older machines, push or pop instructions might have been favored because they were shorter than general store-to-some-offset instructions. So using those instructions necessitated pushing in reverse of the order desired for popping. But we are no longer tied to those instructions.

This is further complicated by the fact that some arguments are passed in registers before the stack is used. Nonetheless, somewhere in the compiler, there is code that analyzes a function call and generates some internal compiler language code to pass the arguments to the function being called. That code might happen to generate that code in reverse argument order, either as an echo of how code used to be written or as a happenstance of how the parsing of function calls operates. When no optimization is used, that internal code might get implemented directly.

However, when optimization is enabled, the operations are likely to get reordered. This is specially so when the arguments are compound expressions, not mere constants or identifiers. If arguments A and C are some expressions that share some common subexpression, say calculation of a location in an array, then the optimizer might well calculate that common expression and store arguments A and C in their designated registers before it proceeds to argument B.

So, the effect you are seeing is likely just a happenstance of how the code is written, possibly influenced by how language parsers are written or by history, but has no significance in modern practicality and is likely to vanish when optimization is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because right-to-left is just as good as left-to-right other than for personal preferences. And personal preferences don't have much significance for code that isn't intended to be read by humans. It's simply a convention chosen by the compiler.

What you're seeing is an implementation detail of the compiler (apparently you have a compiler that decided to pass some of the arguments in registers instead of the stack, as would be the "traditional" way). The CPU wouldn't really care about the order of instructions for register loads, as they are (in your example) not related to each other at all.

The fact that most compilers seem to do the parameter passing in right-to-left order is probably because traditionally, C compilers used to pass arguments on the stack and want the topmost argument on the stack to be the first in the argument list (but that's just another convention).